# Hibernate validation @Pattern

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsf, richfaces

I am using `org.hibernate.validator.Pattern` annotation in my `jsf` managed bean to validate an `<h:inputText>` component.

```
@Pattern(regex="\\W+")
public String getText() {
  return text;
}
```

My question is, is there a way to get the regular expression from a method or EL withought hard-coding it.
For an example

```
@Pattern(regex = getRexEx())
```

OR

```
@Pattern(regex = "#{bean.regEx}")
```

I googled and found that the `regEx` should be a constant. However there can be a alternative way to accomplish this.

Comment: Why do need this do you want to change it at run time? And I agree with the below answer.

Comment: Sure, I also think that the below answer is correct, logical and descriptive. But I am still waiting to find whether there is any other approach.:)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994864/how-would-i-specify-a-hibernate-pattern-annotation-using-a-regular-expression for define constraints at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments to an annotation need to be compile time constants, so no, it's not possible to specify a run time expression as the argument for @Pattern. It's also not possible to pass an EL expression as argument and have it do anything because, well, that's simply not how the pattern validator was written.

What you *can* do however, is define your own a validator class that takes a form of an EL expression and validates the bean property against it. Good luck with the context management for that though! Not a simple task.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. It seems your suggestion is the only solution for that. But you know I am not going to test it. :)