# How to read the regex pattern from property file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Pattern(regexp = "{A-Za-z0-9}*")
private String name;
```

Above regex, I want to read from the property file

Comment: `"${your.config.key:-default value}"`. Have you tried that and it does not work or haven't you tried it and don't know about it?

Comment: @knittl I tried several times without success, IntelliJ put a red highlight after '${' with the message "Number expected"

Comment: @DonFabiolas but what does the Java compiler say?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible from Spring 3.0.1 afterwords. You can do it like a regular property value binding. Inside your `application.yml`

```
my:
  regex:
    charOrNumber: '{A-Za-z0-9}*'
```

And then in your Java class:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "${my.regex.charOrNumber}")
```

Comment: I tried several times without success, IntelliJ put a red highlight after '${' with the message "Number expected"

Comment: @DonFabiolas this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69524543/intellij-does-not-recognize-parameters-in-cucumber-step-definitions-number-exp